# Trying to move text next to eachother in footer

Tags: html, css, footer

How can I move text next to each other in my footer? Im trying to have 3 columns next to each other and right now I only have one column and I cant figure out how to get two others next to it.

Shop and Learn
        
Mac

```
    <br><a href="footer.html">iPad</a>

    <br><a href="footer.html">iPhone</a>

    <br><a href="footer.html">Watch</a>

    <br><a href="footer.html">TV</a>

    <br><a href="footer.html">Music</a>

    <br><a href="footer.html">iTunes</a>

    <br><a href="footer.html">iPad</a>

    <br><a href="footer.html">Accessories</a>

    <br><a href="footer.html">Gift Cards</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, divide the links...

```
<div class="linklist">
<a href="footer.html">iPad</a><br>
<a href="footer.html">iPhone</a><br>
<a href="footer.html">Watch</a><br>
</div>

<div class="linklist">
<a href="footer.html">TV</a><br>
<a href="footer.html">Music</a><br>
<a href="footer.html">iTunes</a><br>
</div>

<div class="linklist">
<a href="footer.html">iPad</a><br>
<a href="footer.html">Accessories</a><br>
<a href="footer.html">Gift Cards</a><br>
</div>
```

And then style!

```
.linklist {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Expand upon the css however suits you, but this will get the links split between three columns. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [**column-count**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) CSS property. Check below example

```html
<ul style="-webkit-column-count: 3;-moz-column-count: 3;column-count: 3;">
  <li><a href="footer.html">iPad</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="footer.html">iPhone</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="footer.html">Watch</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="footer.html">TV</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="footer.html">Music</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="footer.html">iTunes</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="footer.html">iPad</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="footer.html">Accessories</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="footer.html">Gift Cards</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a few divs to divide the content and add some css to align it as required

```
 <div class="col">      
       <a>content</a>       
       <a>content</a>      
       <a>content</a>    
    </div>    
    <div class="col">    
      <a>content</a>      
      <a>content</a>  
      <a>content</a>  
   </div>    
   <div class="col">  
      <a>content</a>
      <a>content</a>    
      <a>content</a>  
  </div>
```

Now set the CSS:

```
   .col{
        width: 33%;
        float: left;
    } 
   .col a{
         float: left;
         width: 100%;
         margin: 2px;
    }
```

I haven't tested it,  writing on my mobile.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="footer.html" class = "col1">iPad</a>
    <a href="footer.html" class = "col2">iPhone</a>
    <a href="footer.html" class = "col3">Watch</a> <br/>
    <a href="footer.html" class = "col1">TV</a>
    <a href="footer.html" class = "col2">Music</a>
    <a href="footer.html" class = "col3">iTunes</a>
```

CSS Styles: 
.col1

```
    {
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                margin-right: 50px;
            }
            .col2
            {
                float: left;
                margin-right: 50px;
            }
            .col3
            {
                float: left;
                margin-right: 50px;
            }
```

Hope this helped. You can find plenty of answers in stack overflow as well as in google.